# {"code":"PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR","fatal":false}

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL, and I am having difficulties in getting my data from MySQL database.

```
import express from 'express';
import mysql from 'mysql';

const app = express();
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"2000",
    database: "test"
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json('hello this is backend')
})

app.get('/books', (req, res) => {
    const q = "SELECT * FROM books"
    db.query(q, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.json(err)
        }
        else{
            return res.json(data)
        }
    })
})

app.listen(8800, () => {
    console.log('Connected to backend server...');
});
```

as it gives following error on localhost:8800/books/

```
{"code":"PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR","fatal":false}
```

any help would be valuable :)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/RankerO/All-Errors-/blob/main/MySqlErrorPackgeError.md

**It is due to MySQL Package. Need to download mysql2**